# NHibernate: having non-mapped properties on the same object as mapped properties

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I've just refactored my application to get rid of a domain object layer because it was causing NHibernate's lazy loading to break - I spotted this using NHProf and put the blame on AutoMapper.

I've seen others have similar problems. So applying YAGNI I decided to get rid of the DTO layer all together and just have the one set of domain objects - makes sense to me.

However I had a couple of properties on my domain objects that don't exist on my mapped objects. I've moved these to my data layer mapped objects but am now getting NHibernate errors because they aren't virtual.

I don't really want them to be virtual do I? These are either just Getter properties operating on the other mapped properties or set in the business logic.

Anyone have any ideas? Google is not helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I should have tried setting them as virtual.

Lesson learned, even if you're not mapping properties on NHibernate objects, set them as virtual.

Comment: This, among many other reasons, has led me to the conclusion that I really DO need to keep the DTOs around.  NHibernate has forced many restrictions / design decisions that I was unhappy and I currently wouldn't map domain objects directly with NHibernate.

Comment: I'm going to do it until I need it - be very careful with the lazy loading stuff (esp. with automapper) because it will fire off loads of queries. You could make use of caching to fix this, but it caught me out.